# navigator.permissions is undefined in Safari 15.5 (for camera permissions)

Tags: typescript, safari, camera

I have an application which uses camera device.

I use getCameraPermission() method to get the permission from user for camera access. It works for Safari newer versions but not 15.5 version.

```
    public getCameraPermission = (): Promise<CameraPermissionState> => new Promise((resolve) => {
    if ((navigator as any).permissions) {
        var gg = (navigator as any).permissions.query({ name: 'camera' });
        gg.then(({ state }: { state: CameraPermissionState }) => resolve(state))
            .catch(() => resolve(CameraPermissionState.UNKNOWN));
    } else {
        return resolve(CameraPermissionState.UNKNOWN);
    }
})
```

(navigator as any).permissions return undefined if i run it from Safari 15.5 (with Mac) and then i can not detect the camerapermission correctly.

I also dont have an issue for mobile safari.

I checked the relevant subjects in stackoverflow however they were either for GeoLocation or they did not work.

*I can access to cameras
*Safari prompts camera using permission to user, even if user accepts i still get permissions undefined

Any ideas how can i workaround that problem?

Answer (score 0):

The permissions API is still in technical preview, for Safari:

[image]
([source](https://caniuse.com/permissions-api))

As such, you can't use it on older versions.

That `caniuse` page does list a [polyfill](https://github.com/jimmywarting/browser-su), but I don't know if and how well that'd work on Safari 15.5

Comment: Yes it's not supported but i'm trying to find a workaround if possible.

Comment: Which is why I mentioned the polyfill.

Comment: In the given polyfill, there is nothing indicates camera permission. I still can get UserMedia and camera devices without polyfill.

Comment: Then you're apparently out of luck.